# Convert To Bezier Path

Tags: adobe-after-effects

Please help me, I was learning some basic of morphing in after effects, so that I need to use bezier path concept, I was converting a square path to  bezier path, but I was unable to do that. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can't convert a rectangular path to a bezier path in shape layers. This leaves you with 2 options:

1. Create solids and use masks instead of shape layers. There a rectangular path is just a regular bezier curve you can alter.
2. Draw your path for the shape layer with the pen tool, not the rectangle (or elipse) tool.

You can copy a path from illustrator onto a shape layer, but it only works but intersecting with the path that is already there, so I don't see how this could be practical.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you figured it out by now or not but if you were holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key as you created your shapes, the shapes are then automatically converted to bezier paths. If you create your shapes by just clicking and dragging then you'll see the option when you right click the path field.